# How to use angular cache to store on page refresh?

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-cache

I'm attempting to use angular-cache v4.2:
[angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache)
I am unable to get it storing between page refreshes.

I tried to create a codepen, but didn't get very far as I have been unable to inject the module on there. [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJqQpL).

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-cache'])
  .config(function (CacheFactoryProvider) {
    angular.extend(CacheFactoryProvider.defaults, { maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000 });
  })
```

However, even when I get it to create caches, it loses the cache when the page is refreshed - I have tried the three different storage types and haven't been able to get any working on chrome version 39.

Comment: you may want to look into `local storage` as an option for data persistence; which also has wrappers available, such as this one: [angular local storage module](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer with the help of Shehryar's comment. See:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJbxwR)

```
 // To add to local storage
  localStorageService.set('localStorageKey','Now this!');
  // Read that value back
  $scope.value = localStorageService.get('localStorageKey');
```

Using the angular local storage module, this example will store the cache create after a page refresh. It is also possible to add in

```
localStorageService.clearAll();
```

and then refresh the page to remove the initial value.